# how to publish user defined table type as an article in Transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

I am new to replication and trying to use transactional replication. I am trying to publish all data and schema. My stored procedure takes user defined table type as input.

```
CREATE type TableBParam as table
(
    Id Bigint,
    TableAId Bigint not null,
    FieldB1 nvarchar(50)
)

--Deadlock was observed on the save query
go
CREATE PROC SaveTableB
(  
 @val [dbo].[TableBParam] READONLY  
)  
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;  

MERGE [dbo].[TableB] AS T  
USING (SELECT * FROM @val) AS S  
  ON ( T.Id = S.Id)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    update set FieldB1 = S.FieldB1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    insert(TableAId, FieldB1) Values(S.TableAId, S.FieldB1);

END
go
```

when the snapshot agent runs it gives me an error **"Script failed for user defined table type TableBParam"**

I couldn't find an option to specify user defined table types in the article dialog when we setup Local publish. I have also explore the article properties to which didn't help me.

[image]

Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

UDTs are not articles that can be added to a publication directly. They are often used in stored procedures, so when you publish a stored procedure that depends on a UDT, the table type is scripted with the procedure itself.

In this case, it looks like the snapshot agent is failing while scripting the UDT. You could investigate the issue by changing the `-OutputVerboseLevel` switch to 2 and look for meaningful error messages in the output.

Another option is to remove the offending procedure from the publication and script it manually, along with its UDT.